# How to remove numbers after decimal point in PIE reports in ssrs 2008 R2

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am  using SSRS 2008 R2.On my pie chart I changed the values to 'Show data Labels' next changed properties to  'pie label to outside' and the data labels show data like "**2546.25**", but I can't figure out how to turn off numbers after decimal.

I just want to show number like "**2546**"
but i tried properties via series label properties like below ,

**Goto->series label properties->Number->Decimal places as 0**

no luck for me

Can anyone give me suggestions?

Comment: how about converting the column value from decimal to integer in the source query?

Comment: Is it possible to convert decimal to integer or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why this doesn't work sometimes, but I've experienced similar issues in different versions.

Anyway, to get around this you can apply any necessary formatting in the **Series Label Properties** -> **Label data** property:

[image]

For example, if your series data expression is `=Sum(Fields!MyField.Value)` you should set the data label expression to `=Format(Sum(Fields!MyField.Value), "N0")`

This gives you direct control over what is shown in the labels and how the data is formatted.